# Methodology searching for an asymptotic solution of an inequation

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Let us suppose that we have $Q(x)$ an increasing and positive function, and we seek the (approximated) smallest $i$ such that

\begin{equation}
Q(i) \geq n
\end{equation}

If we can estimate $Q(i)$ using a $\Theta$ notation, can we estimate the smallest $i$ using this same Landau notation?

What about the other notations? $o$, $\sim$, ...?

Let us take an example. Suppose that $Q(i)=\Theta(f(i))$ where $f$ has an inverse $f^{−1}$. Can we say that the smallest $i$ satisfying the inequation is in $\Theta(f^{−1}(n))$ or in $O(f^{−1}(n))$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is $Q$ defined: real numbers, integers, naturals?

Comment: This depends heavily on what $Q$ is... Take, for example, $\operatorname{li}(x) - \pi(x)$ , the logarithmic integral and prime counting function. Of course, in this case our function isn't positive and increasing, so it's not a perfect example, but it goes to show how hard asymptotic analysis can be

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thank you for your comments. $Q$ is defined on integers and takes integer values.

Comment: My post has slightly been updated with another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the claim fails even for $Q=rf+O(1)$ with a constant $r$ different from $1$. Indeed, let $f(i)=\log_2 i$. Then $f^{-1}(n)=2^n$. But if $Q(i)=\lfloor 2\log_2 i\rfloor$ then $i \simeq 2^{n/2}$, if $Q(i)=\lfloor (1/2)\log_2 i\rfloor$ then $i \simeq 2^{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you an idea for the other Landau notations?

Comment: @Dingo13 It seems that the condition $Q=rf+O(1)$ in my counterexample implies $Q=B(f)$ for all  [Bachmann–Landau notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) $B$ but $o$, $\omega$, and $\sim$. Maybe the cases of $o$ and $\omega$ imply only one-side bounds, but the case of $\sim$ implies two-side  bounds. I’ll think about this.

Comment: @Dingo13 It seems that the claim fails even for $Q\sim f$, when $Q-f=O(1)$. I did not checked precisely the following calculation, but it looks plausible. Let $f(i)=\sqrt {\log_2 i}$. Then $f^{-1}(n)=2^{n^2}$. But if $Q(i)=\lfloor\sqrt {\log_2 i}\rfloor-2$ then $i \ge 2^{(n+1)^2}$, if $Q(i)=\lfloor\sqrt {\log_2 i}\rfloor+2$ then $i\le 2^{(n-1)^2}$. Are you interested in one-side bounds for $o$ and $\omega$?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially
asking for the approximate inverse
of $Q$.

Sometimes this is easy:
If 
$Q(i)
=i^m
$
then
$Q^{-1}(n)
=n^{1/m}
$.

Sometimes only as
approximate result can be  gotten:
If
$Q(i) = i\cdot \ln(i)
$
then
$Q^{-1}(n)
\approx \dfrac{n}{\ln(n)}
$
with additional error terms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you say that $Q^{-1}(n) = \Theta(\frac{n}{\log n})$? Let us take another example. Suppose that $Q(i)=\Theta(f(i))$ where $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$. Can we say that the smallest $i$ satisfying the inequation is in $\Theta(f^{-1}(n))$ or in $O(f^{-1}(n))$ ? Thank you again

Comment: I think that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can we prove this is correct ?